# How to fixed width column of Material-Table ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using `Material-table` in my project and I'd like to apply a `max-width` to every column. I want to do that because the specific column is misconfiguring my table.

[image]

For example if I do, `max-width: '150px'` in that column,  I get this below. The text overrides everything.

[image]

Comment: You should try changing `tableLayout` value, full example on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555414/10569220).

Comment: Have you tried `width` property on `column`?