# How can I adjust the following implementation of react material-table to customize column width, and to avoid cell wrapping of value?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I use material-table, react, and material-ui.

I've really struggled to get material-table column widths set properly. I've googled a number of stack and git posts (e.g. [one example](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/291), [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539462/material-table-how-change-width-of-the-columns)), all of which have made various suggestions.. none have worked for me.

Currently I am creating my table as follows (notice all the attempts to set width, max-width, min-width. I've tried many combinations of these).

I've also tried many combinations of the options parameters in an attempt to customize the table in a fashion consistent with the two questions at the bottom of this post.

```
return (
        <div className={classes.root} >
            <MaterialTable
                data={data}
                title={title}
                icons={tableIcons}
                onSelectionChange={(rows) => setSelectedRows(rows)}
                options={{
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "#01579b",
                        color: "#FFF"
                    },
                    tableLayout: "fixed",
                    rowStyle: {
                        overflowWrap: 'break-word'
                    },
                    selection: true,
                }}
                columns={[
                    {
                        title: "Id",
                        field: "id",
                        type: "numeric",
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: "purple",
                            width: "5%"
                        },
                        cellStyle: {width: "5%", maxWidth: "5%", overflow: "hidden"},
                        width: "5%"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Label",
                        field: "label",
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: "blue",
                            width: "75%"
                        },
                        cellStyle: {width: "75%", maxWidth: "75%", overflow: "hidden"},
                        width: "75%"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Time",
                        field: "time",
                        type: "string",
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            width: "20%"
                        },
                        cellStyle: {width: "20%", maxWidth: "20%", overflow: "hidden"},
                        width: "20%"
                    }
                ]}
                actions={[
                    {
                        icon: () => <SaveAlt />,
                        tooltip: "Save User",
                        onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
                    }
                ]}
                components={{
                    Action: (props) => (
                        <Button
                            onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
                            color="primary"
                            variant="text"
                            style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
                            size="small"
                        >
                            Save
                        </Button>
                    )
                }}

            />
        </div>
    );
```

where

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        maxWidth: "600px",
        paddingTop: "2px"
    },
    margin: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    extendedIcon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));
```

My table looks like the following:

[image]

The following shows the CSS for the "td" element.
[image]

Oddly the width is set to 200px, and nothing I seem to do modifies this. Even when I change the value in the dev tools to something like 40px, this does not change the actual column width.

I am able to change the header width (in developer tools) for that column and then things look ok, but nothing I do in the code has allowed me to change the header width in this same fashion.

[image]

If I do the following for the ID column, one would think that it would set the width for the header, but it doesnt. It still shows up as 200px.

```
{
                        title: "Id",
                        field: "id",
                        type: "numeric",
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            width: "80px"
                        },
                    },
```

[image]

Per the suggestion made in one of the comments, I've also tried [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-change-width-of-column-kty8g?file=/src/App.js) code.. to no avail:

```
export default function MyCustomTable(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const tableRef = React.createRef();

    const tableColumns = [
        { title: "Lorem ipsum", field: "lorem", width: "10%" },
        { title: "Name", field: "name", width: "80%" },
        { title: "Custom status", field: "customStatus", width: "10%" }
    ];

    const tableData = [
        {
            lorem: "lorem",
            name: "name",
            customStatus: "customStatus"
        }
    ];

    return (
        <div className={classes.root} >
        <MaterialTable
            tableRef={tableRef}
            columns={tableColumns}
            data={tableData}
            title="Change Column Width Example"
            options={{
                tableLayout: "fixed"
            }}
        />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

I've also tried to strip out all of my application except for the materialtable.. same styling problem.

[image]

Two questions:

1. How do I make the ID column narrower?
2. How do I configure the date so that it does not wrap onto a second row?

Comment: did you check out this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539462/material-table-how-change-width-of-the-columns

Comment: @urirot I did.. it was one of the many that gave me clues.. but I dont see anything in that thread that I havent already tried.

Comment: In fact I've tried pretty much exactly what you see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-change-width-of-column-kty8g?file=/src/App.js   

In fact I was able to pull exactly that implementation into my component, and I see the same problem:

Comment: @urirot I added the attempt at the code from the codesandbox in the link you referenced.. I also added the image that shows the exact same problem. Even though it works in codesandbox, it does not work in my app

Comment: in your code, did you remove all of your custom styling when you tried using the codesandbox example? if not, try having only what the example show and then gradually adding your styles, to see what is overriding the width percentage

Comment: @urirot Yes.. I've eliminated all the styling that is different. In fact I also have used the developer tools to compare and contrast every style element. They are the same.

Comment: @urirot In fact ive taken that suggestion to the extreme..  I've stripped down the entire app.. and I am only rendering the sandbox code.. same exact problem. the columns are not sizing properly.

Comment: Interesting. did you compare the package.json as well?

Comment: These are his dependencies:

"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.10.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "material-table": "1.60.0",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },

Comment: And mine are all greater than those versions:

"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"material-table": "^1.69.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I see you opened an issue in their github repo. hope that works out. I don't know what your context is, but I would try using just the material-ui tables or some other package

Comment: @urirot I appreciate all your help. The fact that I stripped it down to a barebones app and still see the problem.. was motivated by your help.. Ty much